# Como abrir uma Infobox ao clicar no marcador BING MAPS

Tags: api, maps

Galera, tive que trocar o mapa do google pelo do bing, e agora nao consigo fazer com que ao clicar no marcador abra uma infobox. O evento é chamado, e ele seta as configurações mas simplesmentes não aparece...Quando eu adiciono um marcador no mapa, ou varios funciona, quando eu manipulo qualquer coisa funciona, menos ao abrir o infobox... Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Mostrarei as propriedades e as duas funções q nao fazem oq deveria...
Já até tentei usar a função q eu vi numa resposta tem o hideInfobox,display info box e tbm nao apareceu....

```
  var config = {
      map: undefined,
      infobox: undefined,
      latlng: undefined,
      marcador: undefined,
      carregado: false
   }
   function MapearImoveis(position, imovel, icone) {
       //faz umas coisas aq...........

       Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(config.marcador, 'click', function (event) {
        abrirInfobox(imovel, event); //chama quando clico
     });

     config.map.entities.push(config.marcador);
     }

     function abrirInfobox(imovel, marcador) {
     var info = $("#info");
     //crio o html q vai no infobox 
     ...
     //

    config.infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(marcador.location, { visible: true });
    config.infobox.setHtmlContent(info.html());
    config.map.entities.push(config.infobox);

    document.getElementById("infoFoto").onerror = function (e) {
    e.target.src = "../Content/imagens/imovel_sem_imagem.jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, era só setar o config.infobox.setMap(config.map).